# magento Cannot retrieve currency rate?

Tags: magento, currency

magento Cannot retrieve currency rate .

when i import currency rate from . System->Manage Currency->Rates .

Then click the import button i got the following error can you any one help me .

Cannot retrieve rate from http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR.

Comment: the website http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR is down.

Comment: Any other way of import currency is available in magento .